# Using grunt js to both minify and concatenate without a *.con.js file

Tags: javascript, concatenation, minify, gruntjs

I've been using grunt.js to concatenate and then minify javascript files. The way I've been accomplishing this task leaves me with an extra script.con.js file (the concatenated file). I don't find it really necessary other than staging a concatenated file to minify. What am I missing in my example below?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
            'app/webroot/js/script.con.js': [
                'app/webroot/js/plugins/plugins.js',
                'app/webroot/js/main.js'
            ]
        },
        min: {
            'app/webroot/js/script.min.js': 'app/webroot/js/script.con.js'
        },
        watch: {
            files: ['app/webroot/js/main.js'],
            tasks: 'concat min'
        }
    });

    // Default task.
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'concat min');

};
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

if a minify task exists which first concats and then minifys, you could use that task (i dont think there is such a task until now).

you can delete the con.js file with some clean task: https://github.com/reputation/grunt-clean

Comment: Thank you hereandnow78! I'll look into using that :)

Answer (score 2):

Concatenation and minification works for me like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    min: {
        dist: {
            src: ['lib/js/file1.js', 'lib/js/file2.js'],
            dest: 'lib/js/result.min.js'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what plugin are you configuring there?

Comment: I think thats a leftover before grunts plugin system took place. You should give grunt-contrib-uglify a try for javascript minification.